# angular material selectbox issue with the body height 100%

Tags: angular-material

I have sidebar having body height 100%. If i use **md-select** inside **md-content**, the options are displaying at top of the page.

How do i fix the issue?

```
body,
body > div {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body > div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Pls show your angular material code

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by applying the **display: flex** to body element,

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer This

```html
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  
 
  <script type="text/javascript">    
  
    angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);
  </script>
   <md-input-container flex >
        <label >Type</label>
        <md-select ng-model="txtType" style="width:250px;">
            <md-option>First</md-option>
            <md-option>Second</md-option>
        </md-select>       
      
    </md-input-container>
</body>
</html>
```